# creating custom protocol whose method get called itself like tableview's method or uislider's method

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, protocols, sprite

I am creating a cocos 2d game in which i need to get the coordinates of my sprite whenever there is slight movement in its coordinate ,say .1.I thought i could make a custom protocol for it which calls its method whenever coordinate changes just like :-

```
 [someSlider addTarget:self action:@selector(slider:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

which get called for every value changed of UISlider.

So my questions are -:
1)Is it possible to do so?

2) if not , can any one suggest me some proper way to solve my problem.

SImply , my sprite is moving from position A to B and i want to know every single coordinate it went through while movement from A to B.

Answer (score 2):

You could do that by subclassing `UIControl`. Then you can register targets like in your UISlider example and send the actions via

```
- (void)sendActionsForControlEvents:(UIControlEvents)controlEvents;
```

Since I suppose you are already subclassing `CCSprite`, you will have to implement it yourself, i.e. using a delegate:

```
@protocoll MyClassDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)myClassDidSomething:(MyClass*)myClass   
@end

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<MyClassDelegate>delegate;
```

Then (after assigning the delegate of course) you can call the defined methods on the delegate:

```
[self.delegate myClassDidSomething:self];
```